# serverError:class javax.faces.el.EvaluationException could not execute query

Tags: mysql, hibernate, tomcat

I am getting this error from host server. I am using mysql database,tomcat and hibernate orm tool.
How can I solve this problem? Can you help me please?

Comment: I'm having this problem too, but I'm using Glassfish instead, I really don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too.
You should take a look if there's object that is not initialized, then you shoul see if the tables are specified correctly (this is more common if you develop in Windows and deploy in Linux or vice-versa).

For mote details take a look here:
[Manager Bean do not returns when the project is online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956866/manager-bean-do-not-returns-when-the-project-is-online)