# Manager Bean do not returns when the project is online

Tags: jsf, jpa, jsf-2, eclipselink, glassfish-3

I have a JSF project working with JPA, I do this : retrive some data from mysql database then plot the data in a chart.

Locally works pretty  fine, as you can see here:
[image]

So I deploy the project in my GlassFish 3 Open Source, which is running in a EC2 instance, then I try to make the same operation again but it seems the ManagedBean do not returns to the page correctly:
[image]

This is my ManageBean :

```
@ManagedBean(name="reportc")
@SessionScoped
public class ReportControl implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3269125738504434502L;

    @EJB LogEAO logEAO;

    private int quantity;

    @NotNull(message="informe um intervalo")
    private String time;

    @NotNull(message="informe um ponto")
    private String point;

    private Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        quantity = 1;
    }

    public String getDataAsJson() {
        return new Gson().toJson(data);
    }

    public String generateReport(){
        this.setTitles();
        this.getValues(getLog());

        return "/showroom/report.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }
    .. methods and get's and set's
```

I already look in into my server.log to see if there's something wron but it seems everything is alright.

```
[#|2012-03-31T14:30:06.594+0000|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, image/structure/pic-1.gif.|#]

[#|2012-03-31T14:30:15.558+0000|FINE|glassfish3.1.1|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/ec2-user/usr/local/glassfish3/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/BrainSet/WEB-INF/classes/_BrainSet.sql|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=null;MethodName=null;|SELECT ID, TIME, VALUE, id_point FROM log WHERE (((id_point = ?) AND (TIME >= ?)) AND (TIME <= ?))
        bind => [3 parameters bound]|#]

[#|2012-03-31T14:30:15.585+0000|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EXECUTION TIME:0:0|#]

[#|2012-03-31T14:30:15.585+0000|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|LOGS SIZE : 0|#]

[#|2012-03-31T14:30:16.690+0000|WARNING|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, image/structure/pic-1.gif.|#]

[#|2012-03-31T14:35:53.578+0000|FINE|glassfish3.1.1|org.eclipse.persistence.session.file:/home/ec2-user/usr/local/glassfish3/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/BrainSet/WEB-INF/classes/_BrainSet.sql|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=Thread-2;ClassName=null;MethodName=null;|SELECT ID, TIME, VALUE, id_point FROM log WHERE (((id_point = ?) AND (TIME >= ?)) AND (TIME <= ?))
        bind => [3 parameters bound]|#]

[#|2012-03-31T14:35:53.605+0000|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|EXECUTION TIME:0:0|#]

[#|2012-03-31T14:35:53.605+0000|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=28;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|LOGS SIZE : 0|#]
```

I really don't know why this is happening, besides is my first time trying to deploy a project which use JPA and JSF together.
What could be doing this ?

**EDIT:**
Just one more thing, in local mode when I click to generate the report it takes some seconds to go to the database, make the maths and return to my page, but when it's in production mode when I click to generate the report it just refresh the page, why is that happening ?
I really need to know why ... help me out guys, please.

**EDIT 2:**

You guys can see it online here:
http://50.19.242.172:8080/BrainSet/showroom/report.xhtml

Comment: have you added some print outs to see that the data that is being returned in local mode is being returned in production? also,, are there any errors in firebug console?

Comment: @Daniel I did what you said, in local mode it show the prints pretty fine but in production it doesn't.

Comment: Are you using some homegrown JS/jQuery code to send ajax requests to the server without involving JSF? Are those ajax request URLs correct? Did you for example hardcode "http://localhost" anywhere in those URLs?

Comment: @BalusC, I'm not using JS/JQuery to send ajax request to the server, just pure JSF. What you mean by 'ajax request URL correct' ?
I think it's correct because after get the values from my database I have to show them in my page which I send to it a JSON as you teach me in some previous thread.

The hardcore url is this :
http://50.19.242.172:8080/BrainSet/showroom/report.xhtml

Comment: Okay. Did you check for any JS errors in JS console of the browser builtin webdeveloper toolset? (press F12 in Chrome/Firebug/IE9 and check *Console*). Look like the graph data wasn't properly received or processed. It would also be worth the effort to investigate the HTTP traffic in *Net/Network* section to spot the difference in request/response headers/body between localhost and production.

Comment: I suggest you to place more print outs from the bottom to the top of your data flow... and look whats going on with your data and where it is being lost...

Comment: I just played a bit with the url and i did get some charts... also i got some el expressions errors from time to time ... take a look http://i41.tinypic.com/1ffzar.png

Comment: @Daniel how did you get this charts ? How did you do it ? It works tough, what you think could create this el expressions errors ?

Comment: @BalusC I'm gonna do that as you said, but for now, I don't see any error in hearders or body even localhost or production.

Comment: @BalusC the only error that appears with F12 key pressed in Chrome is "event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future." Any tip ?

Comment: Ignore the event.layerX error... its jQuery messages... it wont do any harm...

Comment: What implementation of jpa and jsf are you using localy. Is it glassfish 3 also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was :

I had to give permissions to some user in MySQL, enable the remote connection in MySQL, put JDBC driver in `glassfish_installation\glassfish\modules\` and restart it, initialize the `logEAO` and put the annotation `@Table(name="table_name")` because it depends of each file system in operationals system as can be seen here:

[JPA: MySQL says table don't exist, but it exist actually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093718/jpa-mysql-says-table-dont-exist-but-it-exist-actually).

Answer (score 1):

Just played with the chart again...

I do get charts properly... could it be that you had no data gathered in the production in the beginning...? Cause now there is

Also i'm getting alerts saying

> serverError: class javax.faces.el.EvaluationException For input string: "true"

check you EL expressions related to the "drop downs" of the chart....

b.t.w here another successful screenshot : [image]

So it seems like working... **you might need to redefine your question...**

Comment: Everytime I enter I could see the alert but it never generates a chart, I've even tried using the data of your ss

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Ctrl + F5 in the browser to force reload page ?