# Spring + Hibernate annotations error "is not mapped"

Tags: spring, hibernate, annotations

I use Spring + Hibernate with annotations and i got the following error :

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Produit is not mapped [from Produit]
```

it appens when i call this function :

```
public List<Produit> getListeProduit() {

    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Produit").list();
}
```

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <mapping class="port.domain.Produit" />
</session-factory>     
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Produit class are annoted well with @Entity, @Table
ID with @Id, @Column, @GeneratedValue
The others columns with @Column

Here is my bean SessionFactory in my XXX-servlet.xml :

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>
```

EDIT : Entity Code

```
@Entity
@Table(name="produit")
public class Produit implements Serializable{

@Id
@Column(name="produit_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int produitId;

@Column(name="produit_nom")
private String produitNom;

public void setProduitId(int i) {
    produitId = i;
} 

public int getProduitId() {
    return produitId;
} 

public void setProduitNom(String s) {
    produitNom = s;
} 

public String getProduitNom() {
    return produitNom;
} 
}
```

I know there are many threads about this problem but i don't find any correct issues.
I understand that Hibernate can't mapped my class but i don't know why ...

Where could the problem come from ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Post the entity code please.

Comment: I add an edit to my post

Comment: Stupid question, but is the mysql instance on a Unix box or windows?

Comment: Mysql instance is on Windows

Comment: Ok, It seems like that could be an issue if my sql were on unix, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093718/jpa-mysql-says-table-dont-exist-but-it-exist-actually

Comment: Ok, another question.  Have you successfully wired up any other entities?  So is this an issue with just the produit entity or is this issue across your application?  This will tell us if its a config issue or a one time mapping issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the problem is trivial: you should use `javax.persistence.Entity` instead of Hibernate-specific `org.hibernate.annotations.Entity`. The latter was deprecated in Hibernate in favour of JPA annotations where possible.

That's exactly what you didn't show, so hope it's a lucky shot :)

Comment: Oh my god ... it works finally you're right ... why `org.hibernate.annotations.Entity`doesn't works ?

Comment: It was deprecated, Hibernate now uses JPA-specific annotations where possible.

Comment: So with Hibernate, i have to prefer JPA annotations instead of hibernate annotations in my entity ?

Comment: Exactly. Hibernate falls back to its own annotations when there are no analogs in JPA. Or both ways work from time to time, for such annotations processing you can find in Hibernate 'if this is JPA-specific, then this behavior. Else - that behavior'.